# How to set up IIS active directory with react application

Tags: reactjs, authentication, iis, active-directory

I have the react application that uses JWT token and when user wants to access server he will be asked to put his name and password and will get token as a response. I have my custom loging page.

Now we have the requirement to authenticate users against Active directory of IIS. So users that are already authenticated on their computers should not be asked again for credentials.

I see window with login (not mine but from browser) [image]

this window keep asking me for the credentials. I do not see any outgoing requests from this window.

**Question**:  How I can control behavior of this window from my react application? Maybe there is some libraries for this purposes. I need to set up react application or IIS and hide this window and allow user to login silently if he already authenticated.

Comment: This window is because authentication is enabled in IIS. You can check whether Windows authentication or basic authentication is enabled in the authentication module under the site. Disable it.

Comment: @BruceZhang this is a requirement to have authentication enabled in IIS.

Comment: Has your IIS joined the Active Directory domain? If this is Windows authentication, just enter the account in the AD domain to pass.

Comment: I need to control this window from my react app. Passing the username/pass works out of the box.